# Parse the SysML generated from Enterprise Architect in Java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, uml, papyrus

I have a SysML file generated from Enterprise Architect with extension XMI, and I want to parse it to get the object inside SysML file in Java by using EMF, UML2 and Papyrus plugins.

I tried to new a EMF project and import this SysML file, but failed. It said that there is some illegal values inside this file.

Then I tried to write a reader to read this, it also doesn't work. The code as follow:

```
ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
Registry packageRegistry = resourceSet.getPackageRegistry();
packageRegistry.put(XMI_NAMESPACE, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
packageRegistry.put(UML_NAMESPACE, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
packageRegistry.put(SysmlPackage.eNS_URI, SysmlPackage.eINSTANCE);
//packageRegistry.put(ADA_NAMESPACE, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
//packageRegistry.put(VERILOG_NAMESPACE, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
//packageRegistry.put(ARCGIS_NAMESPACE, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
//packageRegistry.put(EAUML_NAMESPACE, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
//packageRegistry.put(THE_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_NAMESPACE,UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
// Add the load option
resourceSet.getLoadOptions().put(XMIResource.OPTION_RECORD_UNKNOWN_FEATURE, Boolean.TRUE);
// Deine the extension to factory map
Map<String, Object> extensionToFactoryMap = resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap();
UMLResourceFactoryImpl umlResourceFactory = new UMLResourceFactoryImpl();
extensionToFactoryMap.put(XMI2UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, umlResourceFactory);
URI uri = URI.createFileURI(xmiFile.getPath());
Model umlModel = UML2Util.load(resource, uri, UMLPackage.Literals.MODEL);
System.out.println(umlModel);
```

This code works with SysML generated by Papyrus, but does not work with the file generated from Enterprise Architect.

As the comments inside, in the head of SysML file, there is a lot of namespaces particular. The namespaces as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" xmlns:thecustomprofile="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/thecustomprofile/1.0" xmlns:Ada="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/Ada/1.0" xmlns:Verilog="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/Verilog/1.0" xmlns:ArcGIS="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/ArcGIS/1.0" xmlns:sysml="http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/20080501/SysML-profile" xmlns:SysML="http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/20120322/SysML" xmlns:EAUML="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/EAUML/1.0">
    <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
    <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">
        ....
```

And I want to get the imformation in the tag ....

Could someone helps me?

**Edit:**

1. The plugins I used in my code:

---

```
org.eclipse.emf.common;bundle-version="2.11.0",
org.eclipse.emf.ecore;bundle-version="2.11.1",
org.eclipse.emf.mapping;bundle-version="2.9.0",
org.eclipse.uml2.common;bundle-version="2.1.0",
org.eclipse.uml2.uml;bundle-version="5.1.0",
org.apache.log4j;bundle-version="1.2.15",
org.junit;bundle-version="4.12.0",
org.eclipse.papyrus.sysml;bundle-version="1.1.3"
```

2. The code I use could parse the SysML generated by Papyrus, and also by IBM Rhapsody. Unfortunately, I need to parse the file generated by EA. In addition, I tried to use Rhapsody to import the SysML generated by EA, and then exported a new SysML file from Rhapsody. This time I could parse the new SysML file.
3. The errors showed when I parse SysML from EA just like follow:

   ```
   Line: 3501 : Value 'org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.impl.AnyTypeImpl@1ddeb95 (eClass: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl@77270b15 (name: ActivityEdge) (instanceClassName: null) (abstract: false, interface: false)) (mixed: null, anyAttribute: [XMI_2.1:idref=EAID_B206112C_3845_4058_8987_AAB974C081D8])' is not legal. (file:/home/pzhengshuai/workspace-papyrus/SysMLReader/resource/import/export_file_xmi_2.1/eaexample_model.xmi, 3501, 77)
   ```

and somes like this

```
Line: 1989 : Unresolved reference 'EAID_425E703B_8FB1_4be3_9264_C470555CFF8F'. (file:/home/pzhengshuai/workspace-papyrus/SysMLReader/resource/import/export_file_xmi_2.1/eaexample_model.xmi, 1989, 73)
```

4. A guess:

I guess that maybe my code could not recognize the namespaces particular in EA SysML file. If we could find the schemas or somethings define the namespaces in EA, and add them into the SysML file, maybe code will work. But I have not found any files related.

Comment: Side note on code quality: don't do everything in one method. Any class, method, ... should have one responsibility. Stuffing 10, 15, 20+ lines of code into one method, all working on different "levels of abstractions" does lead to code that is much harder to read and maintain. Check out "clean code" by Robert Martin if you are interested in how to write code ... that is not like this ;-)

Comment: Which uml2 do you use? because the XMI generated by EA seems to be UML2.1 not UML2.5 (last uml2 version) so you could have some issue to load it...

Comment: UML2.1, I tired to import the XMI file generated  by EA into IBM Rhapsody, and then generated a new file by Rhapsody. The new file could be read by my code above.

Comment: As a rough guess you should check the code pages. Try with a plain new model and only US ASCII chars.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what kind of errors you're getting. That would be good to know.

Judging from the XMI above to take a shot in the dark, it appears that Sparx EA is representing SysML as UML with a SysML profile applied to it. That is legitimate, but it is not the same thing as directly using the SysML metamodel. Your code appears to be using the metamodel directly.

Comment: So if there is another way to read the model? I added some infos above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would refer you to @GeertBellekens (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2018133/geert-bellekens). He is an expert in Sparx EA. I don't know a way to flag him here to get his attention, but you can easily look him up on the web.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to contact him. Zhengshuai

Comment: Posting on Sparx' forum usually will get his attention. He's not a Java guy, though.

Comment: My experience is that parsing XMI is a PITA, so I try to avoid that as much as possible. Alternative to the xmi approach would be to skip the export to xmi and read the model from EA directly using the API. You can do that with Java as well, but most of the code you'll find on the web will be C#.

Comment: Two years later! 